# Differential Equations question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here's my problem:

> If $y' = y^2$ and $y(0) = 3$, then find $y(-1)$.

I'm not quite sure what to do with it. What I've watched on Khan Academy doesn't seem to be in the same format as this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = y^2 \implies \dfrac{dy}{y^2} = dx \implies d \left(-\dfrac1y\right) = dx \implies -\dfrac1{y(x)} = x +\text{constant}$$
We are given $y(0) = 3$. This gives us $$-\dfrac13 = \text{constant}$$
Hence, we have
$$-\dfrac1{y(x)} = x - \dfrac13 \implies \dfrac1{y(x)} = \dfrac{1-3x}3 \implies y(x) = \dfrac3{1-3x}$$